# React, executing component's function causes Redux state change which unmounts the component, does the function return at this point?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In situation, where component A's member function dispatches Redux action, which causes upper level container not to render component A on next render, will the function return at this point or is it still executed till the end?

Comment: Hi ! Can you provide an example to your question please ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is still executed till the end. Your store will update instantly but your parent component will only receive updated props after the current function call finishes. Remember, javascript is (almost) always single-threaded.